# If exists then update else insert not working properly in SQL Server Enterprise Edition

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2000

I know it might be a duplicate question but it is really making me frustrated now. I have to insert/update shipper information and I wrote a stored procedure like this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name='usp_Nucleus_LSS_AddShipperInfo' AND type='P')
    DROP PROCEDURE usp_Nucleus_LSS_AddShipperInfo 
GO 

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_Nucleus_LSS_AddShipperInfo 
(
    @ShipperCode varchar(500),
    @ShipperName varchar(500),
    @CustomsClearance decimal,
    @MinCommissionAmount decimal,
    @CommissionPercent decimal,
    @TruckingAmount decimal,
    @ContractNo varchar(50),
    @ConsigneeName varchar(500),
    @SalesPerson varchar(500),
    @Email varchar(500),
    @ContactNo varchar(500),
    @ShipperPriority varchar(50),
    @EntryBy varchar(50),
    @EntryDate datetime,
    @UpdatedBy varchar(50),
    @UpdateDate datetime
)
AS 
DECLARE
    @NewShipperID bigint,
    @OldShipperID bigint 
BEGIN 
    SELECT @OldShipperID = (SELECT ISNULL(ShipperID, 0) AS ShipperID FROM LSS_t_ShipperInfo WHERE ShipperCode = @ShipperCode)
    SELECT @NewShipperID = (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(ShipperID),0) AS ShipperID FROM LSS_t_ShipperInfo)
    IF (@OldShipperID > 0)
        BEGIN 
            UPDATE LSS_t_ShipperInfo SET ShipperName=@ShipperName, CustomsClearance=@CustomsClearance, 
            MinCommissionAmount=@MinCommissionAmount, CommissionPercent=@CommissionPercent, TruckingAmount=@TruckingAmount, 
            ContractNo=@ContractNo, ConsigneeName=@ConsigneeName, SalesPerson=@SalesPerson, Email=@Email, ContactNo=@ContactNo, 
            ShipperPriority=@ShipperPriority, UpdatedBy=@UpdatedBy, UpdateDate=@UpdateDate 
            WHERE ShipperID = @OldShipperID 
        END 
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO LSS_t_ShipperInfo (ShipperID, ShipperCode, ShipperName, CustomsClearance, MinCommissionAmount, 
            CommissionPercent, TruckingAmount, ContractNo, ConsigneeName, SalesPerson, Email, ContactNo, ShipperPriority, EntryBy, 
            EntryDate, UpdatedBy, UpdateDate) VALUES (@NewShipperID+1, @ShipperCode, @ShipperName, @CustomsClearance, @MinCommissionAmount, 
            @CommissionPercent, @TruckingAmount, @ContractNo, @ConsigneeName, @SalesPerson, @Email, @ContactNo, @ShipperPriority, @EntryBy, 
            @EntryDate, @UpdatedBy, @UpdateDate)
        END
END 

GO
```

I executed this from my app using a single row and it worked. but next time when i again run it using two rows, it neither inserts nor updates records. I don't understand what is the problem here. I run each query separately and they work fine. Here is my VB.Net code:

```
oDBCmd.Connection = oDBCon
                oDBCmd.CommandText = "usp_Nucleus_LSS_AddShipperInfo"
                oDBCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                oDBCmd.CommandTimeout = 0
                nResult = -1

                oDBCmd.Parameters.Add("@ShipperCode", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = DGMAIN.Rows(i).Cells("DGMAIN_SHIPPER_CODE").Value.ToString()
                oDBCmd.Parameters.Add("@ShipperName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = DGMAIN.Rows(i).Cells("DGMAIN_SHIPPER_NAME").Value.ToString()
                oDBCmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomsClearance", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = DGMAIN.Rows(i).Cells("DGMAIN_CUSTOMS_CLEARANCE").Value.ToString()
                oDBCmd.Parameters.Add("@MinCommissionAmount", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = DGMAIN.Rows(i).Cells("DGMAIN_MIN_COMMISSION_AMOUNT").Value.ToString()
                oDBCmd.Parameters.Add("@CommissionPercent", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = DGMAIN.Rows(i).Cells("DGMAIN_COMMISSION_PERCENT").Value.ToString()
                oDBCmd.Parameters.Add("@TruckingAmount", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = DGMAIN.Rows(i).Cells("DGMAIN_TRUCKING_AMOUNT").Value.ToString()
                oDBCmd.Parameters.Add("@ContractNo", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = DGMAIN.Rows(i).Cells("DGMAIN_CONTRACT_NO").Value.ToString()
                oDBCmd.Parameters.Add("@ConsigneeName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = DGMAIN.Rows(i).Cells("DGMAIN_CONSIGNEE_NAME").Value.ToString()
                oDBCmd.Parameters.Add("@SalesPerson", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = DGMAIN.Rows(i).Cells("DGMAIN_SALES_PERSON").Value.ToString()
                oDBCmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = DGMAIN.Rows(i).Cells("DGMAIN_EMAIL").Value.ToString()
                oDBCmd.Parameters.Add("@ContactNo", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = DGMAIN.Rows(i).Cells("DGMAIN_CONTACT_NO").Value.ToString()
                oDBCmd.Parameters.Add("@ShipperPriority", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = DGMAIN.Rows(i).Cells("DGMAIN_SHIPPER_PRIORITY").Value.ToString()
                oDBCmd.Parameters.Add("@EntryBy", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = System.Environment.UserName.ToString().ToUpper()
                oDBCmd.Parameters.Add("@EntryDate", OleDbType.Date).Value = System.DateTime.Now().ToString()
                oDBCmd.Parameters.Add("@UpdatedBy", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = System.Environment.UserName.ToString().ToUpper()
                oDBCmd.Parameters.Add("@UpdateDate", OleDbType.Date).Value = System.DateTime.Now().ToString()

                nResult = oDBCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

I am using VB.Net 2.0 and SQL Server Enterprise edition.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: forgot to mention. It's SQL Server 2000 Enterprise Edition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have look at in your stored procedure , its looking fine .

I think you have problem with your vb.net code. I doubt you are missing the for loop for executing multiple rows of datatable.

Try this code here:

```
    For i As Integer = 0 To DGMAIN.Rows.Count - 1
        oDBCmd = New SqlCommand
        oDBCmd.Connection = oDBCon
        oDBCmd.CommandText = "usp_Nucleus_LSS_AddShipperInfo"
        oDBCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        oDBCmd.CommandTimeout = 0
        nResult = -1

        oDBCmd.Parameters.Add("@ShipperCode", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = DGMAIN.Rows(i)("DGMAIN_SHIPPER_CODE").Value.ToString()
        oDBCmd.Parameters.Add("@ShipperName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = DGMAIN.Rows(i)("DGMAIN_SHIPPER_NAME").Value.ToString()
        oDBCmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomsClearance", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = DGMAIN.Rows(i)("DGMAIN_CUSTOMS_CLEARANCE").Value.ToString()
        oDBCmd.Parameters.Add("@MinCommissionAmount", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = DGMAIN.Rows(i)("DGMAIN_MIN_COMMISSION_AMOUNT").Value.ToString()
        oDBCmd.Parameters.Add("@CommissionPercent", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = DGMAIN.Rows(i)("DGMAIN_COMMISSION_PERCENT").Value.ToString()
        oDBCmd.Parameters.Add("@TruckingAmount", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = DGMAIN.Rows(i)("DGMAIN_TRUCKING_AMOUNT").Value.ToString()
        oDBCmd.Parameters.Add("@ContractNo", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = DGMAIN.Rows(i)("DGMAIN_CONTRACT_NO").Value.ToString()
        oDBCmd.Parameters.Add("@ConsigneeName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = DGMAIN.Rows(i)("DGMAIN_CONSIGNEE_NAME").Value.ToString()
        oDBCmd.Parameters.Add("@SalesPerson", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = DGMAIN.Rows(i)("DGMAIN_SALES_PERSON").Value.ToString()
        oDBCmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = DGMAIN.Rows(i)("DGMAIN_EMAIL").Value.ToString()
        oDBCmd.Parameters.Add("@ContactNo", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = DGMAIN.Rows(i)("DGMAIN_CONTACT_NO").Value.ToString()
        oDBCmd.Parameters.Add("@ShipperPriority", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = DGMAIN.Rows(i)("DGMAIN_SHIPPER_PRIORITY").Value.ToString()
        oDBCmd.Parameters.Add("@EntryBy", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = System.Environment.UserName.ToString().ToUpper()
        oDBCmd.Parameters.Add("@EntryDate", OleDbType.Date).Value = System.DateTime.Now().ToString()
        oDBCmd.Parameters.Add("@UpdatedBy", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = System.Environment.UserName.ToString().ToUpper()
        oDBCmd.Parameters.Add("@UpdateDate", OleDbType.Date).Value = System.DateTime.Now().ToString()

        nResult = oDBCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Next
```

Hope this will helpful to you

Comment: I missed this line in my for loop: **oDBCmd = New SqlCommand()** Now its working. Thanks.